# IE8 jQuery AJAX weirdness

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have an Zend Framework application. I seem to be having an issue with IE8 and jQuery that culminates after several (many) posts. That is, it gets worse and worse as the amount of posts increases. What's happening is, after a while doing data entry without reloading the page, if I try to navigate away or reload the page, IE8 acts really weird/glitchy/shifty and will sometimes tell me it's tried all it can do and will stop trying to load the page. When I reload from there it resets and everything works fine for a while until it builds up and happens again.

To explain a little more about what happens, let's say I have a few other tabs open in IE8--if I try to navigate to another page in the application, IE8 displays some other tab and flickers a little bit before reloading the page and displaying it. If I reload at this point, it does what you would normally expect. If I DON'T reload at this point, the next time the badness builds up again and I try to reload, IE8 will tell me it's not going to try anymore, and I have to manually type the URL into the navigation bar in order to get back to the application.

I have a feeling it has to do with my keypress binding, but I'm not sure why. Has anyone else experienced this and figured out what's going wrong?

Here is my `$(document).ready()` function where the keypress binding occurs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    running = false;
    offset = $("#quantity").html();

    $("#boxNumber").focus();

    $(document).bind("keypress" , function(e){
        var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
        var middleName = document.getElementById('middleName');        
        if (e.which == 13 && (!$("#notes").is(":focus")) && (!$("#submit").is(":focus"))) {
            if (running == false) {
                running = true;
                middleName.value = middleName.value.toUpperCase();
                firstName.value = firstName.value.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
                                    firstName.value.substring(1, firstName.value.size);
                submitForm();
                return false;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (e.which != 13 && $("#middleName").is(":focus") && $("#middleName").val() != '') {
            firstName.focus();
            firstName.value = firstName.value + " " + middleName.value.toUpperCase();
            middleName.value = '';
        }

    });
    bindTdClick();
    bindAutoComplete('oof_name');
    bindAutoComplete('pro_title');
    bindAutoComplete('tags');


    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if (running == false) {
            running = true;
            submitForm();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem mght also be in the `submitForm()` function:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.post("/ajax/files" , $("#files").serialize(), function(data){
        filesReset();
        if (data != "") {
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last").prepend(data);
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").find("td").hide();
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").find("td").fadeIn(1000, function(){ bindTdClick(); });
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").effect("highlight" , {"color": "aqua"}, 1000);

            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:last").remove();
        } else {
            alert("Insert rejected by the server: either inadequate criteria or the server is down.");
            $("#hidden").click();
        }
        running = false;
    });
}
```

Or maybe the `filesReset()` function:

```
function filesReset(){
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    if (lastName.indexOf(',') != -1) {
        lastName = lastName.substring(0, lastName.indexOf(','));
    }
    $("#lastName").val(lastName).focus().select();
    $("#firstName").val("");
    $("#middleName").val("");
    $("#fil_will_recorder_rec_id").val("");
    $(".errors").remove();
    $("#lastInsert table").css({"border-right":"1px solid #D9D9D9"});
    $("#notes").val("");
    //$("#tags").val("");
    $("span").html("");
}
```

Comment: because I don't know any better, I guess.

Comment: maybe because jQuery IS js? native javascript is actually faster in most instances. what kind of question is that...

Comment: At a glance, I don't see anything wrong, but I suspect that at some point in your code something is being bound to the same action over and over (possibly keypress).  You may want to add some alerts or firebug breakpoints to see which segment is being called repeatedly, then go back to IE for testing.

Comment: Doesn't using js instead of jquery actually return different objects? ie `getElementById('foo')` returns a DOM element but `$('#foo')` returns a jquery object (wrapper).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat it's true, but not in all cases. See the `filesReset()` function above: `$("#lastName").val()` which then uses the `indexOf()` method, which is not peculiar to jQuery, I think.

Comment: jQuery always returns a wrapped set of DOM objects. indexOf wasn't commonly available in IE when JQ first had it. You have to use the get or access with [] to pull them out if you need to be certain you're dealing with similar objects.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty heavy on DOM access for every single time you hit a key. If you have a table-heavy app, it's probably making IE8's poor little DOM-manipulating-challenged pea-head explode trying to sort things out.

It looks to me like you're doing some auto-formatting stuff that would make more sense on a blur or focus event on keypress in the !== 13 condition. Move that out of keypress if commenting it out reveals that it's the culprit.

The stuff in the first condition won't get hit the second the === 13 check fails so that should be fine.

Another perf-boosting thing that probably won't fix but wouldn't hurt is to cache all those jQuery selections in cases where HTML isn't getting ripped out and put back in. Just assign all the permanent jq objects in play that get accessed more than once to vars before doing anything else. e.g.

```
var $_someId = $('#some_id');
```

IDs are actually really fast but it can make a big difference for more complicated selections. The same goes for regular DOM API methods which jQuery is just using under the hood.